# Unity hub not logging in

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I downloaded Unity Hub 2021, and when I press login, it takes me to this website: https://api.unity.com/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=unity_hub&response_type=code&code_challenge=Gv3OZwD0-z9TI1h3vy14zdJFU79Gm_RW3RGAmQzcd5E&code_challenge_method=s256&redirect_uri=unityhub%3A%2F%2Flogin&locale=en_US and when it opens, it just displays a black screen and nothing happens; I don't login. Please I need this to be fixed. I have a project I'm working on.

Solved -  I went into Registory Editor and deleted the Unity Hub file. And it magically worked.

Comment: Behind a web proxy?

Comment: What registry key was that specifically? Been trying to get that solved for weeks already. Only way it functions is by downgrading Unity Hub to 2.x and hope it doesn't auto update later. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For me removing registry key didn't help. I was able to solve issue by basically running "Unity Hub.exe" with arguments contains full URL, e.g.: use this command line from the place unity hub executable is located:

`"Unity Hub.exe" unityhub://login/?code=SOMECODE&locale=en&session_state=SOMESESSION`

This URL you can find by looking on the source of html page on which you got in stuck. For sure, this is temp solution just to be unblocked.

Comment: I tried this and still had the same issue. For those trying to find the code, locale, and session state, you can find it in the HTML of the page that opens up when you try to sign in. It is nested in the header inside of a meta tag. You can also find it in the short javascript on the page too.

Comment: @SalAlturaigi isn't is something I wrote in my answer?

Comment: 1. there's no session state in the uri. 2. "&" is not allowed in a command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever changed the Unity Hub path, you'll need to change the path under this key in registry again.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\unityhub

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ5QC.png)

Comment: Any other solutions? Been trying to get that solved for weeks already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to search "unityhub" in registry and exclude it one by one. If you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted that link into the Mozilla browser.
Mozilla opened an alert pop-up.
There was a question if I wanted to choose a default app.
I chose my Unity Hub.exe.
This signed me in and opened the Unity Hub.