# How to bypass admin firewall restriction for Unity Hub logins

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, admin

Although, it is relatively easy to bypass the admin restriction to install Unity Hub, by creating a .bat file like the one below to run the Installer:

```
cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" "%1""
```

How do you login to the Unity Hub without admin rights needed to allow communications through the firewall?

I tried running the firewall app with the .bat file above but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login without admin privileges, use the following command to activate Unity Hub in the Unity folder.

```
"Unity Hub.exe" unityhub://login/?code=SOMECODE&locale=en&session_state=SOMESESSION
```

The argument passed to Unity Hub above is in the head of the blank HTML page generated after logging into Unity from the prompt in Unity Hub.

More details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74033601/19409989